# Couchdb: Adding User Profile Attributes in _user documents

Tags: couchdb, field

When adding new users to Couchdb, is it appropriate to add extra profile fields to the same document?

I know I could have another db with user profiles in it to supplement what is in the _users documents, but is the design of the _users documents static, or would it be ok to add additional fields to the users documents?

Answer (score 3):

The `_users` database is a great place to store information about users. The design of the documents is relaxed, so I would not worry about adding fields. (Removing some *could* be risky though.) You could consider adding an object in the document for all your data:

```
{ "_id": "org.couchdb.user:jhs"
, "_rev": "3-281e87af31d7d8277463732dccc06f65"
, "name": "jhs"
, "type": "user"
, "roles": ["whatever"]
// (etc.)
, "myapp":
  { "profile_photo": "http://example.com/some_photo.png"
  , "favorite_color": "blue"
  }
}
```

The one thing you want to check is the `validate_doc_update` function in `_design/_auth`. Make sure it is not going to prevent you from doing what you need. Currently (probably indefinitely) it does not check any attributes in the document besides those it needs (`type`, `name`, `roles`, etc.).

Just remember that these documents are world-readable. Per-user private data should go in a per-user private database.

Comment: As I understand it, the _users database is not world readable if you assign Reader user(s) or roles to the database. In which case only a user with admin rights or a reader with a role or specifically listed in the "Names" array can read the database.

Comment: That is correct, however the database must be world-readable for users to create accounts. If you don't need anonymous account creation, you can close it off. Still, if a user can see their own document, they can see all other users' documents.